# Linux kernel page fault stack backtrace

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, linux-device-driver

I am using GDB hardware debugger to debug Linux kernel driver. Sometimes, There is a page fault exception.
I connect to processor with GDB and try to backtrace.
GDB prints function calls only for the function after the page fault exception and then prints:

> Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC

How can I backtrace the stack for the function before the exception?

Comment: In my experience, when you *aren't* running gdb, the kernel generally prints a stack backtrace just fine in response to a(n unexpected) kernel page fault. My guess is that gdb isn't managing to successfully navigate past the exception frame on the stack -- which will be quite different than an ordinary function call stack frame. Have you tried just running without the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to say.... most of time I hit page fault + recursive kernel stack trace, most likely stack overflow issue.

I figured out that from the irq_exit(), it was trying to get curret_task_id and task struct was corrupted because of stack overflow. So, dumping initial crash dump but backtrace() also relies on current task struct and keeps hitting page_fault or some kind of non-sense backtrace.....

Enable dynamic